# Debugging error: One of more field types not installed properly

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I attempting to add a folder to a custom Document Set with in a Document library.  However something is not right one or more of the fields and the following error message is not providing me info that would narrow it down.  I am looking for a way to identify and fix the offending fields in library.

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.
  ServerErrorCode=-2130575340
  ServerErrorTraceCorrelationId=0e7a749d-70a8-2000-36cf-14f8618874a2
  ServerErrorTypeName=Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException
  ServerStackTrace=""
  Source=Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder sb)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQuery()
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQuery()
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContextExtensions.ExecuteQueryImplementation(ClientRuntimeContext clientContext, Int32 retryCount, Int32 delay)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileFolderExtensions.CreateFolderImplementation(FolderCollection folderCollection, String folderName, Folder parentFolder)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileFolderExtensions.CreateFolder(Folder parentFolder, String folderName)
       at AddFolderToDocSet.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\PnPCoreTest\AddFolderToDocSet\Program.cs:line 51
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

This is the code I am using to add the folder which leverages the [PNP-Sites-Core library](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-Sites-core).

```
// Get Root Folders collection for 
var projLibRootFldrs = prjLib.RootFolder;
ctx.Load(projLibRootFldrs, pf => pf.Folders);
ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();

// Get the Document Set
Folder f = projLibRootFldrs.EnsureFolder("Test1");

f.CreateFolder("foo"); // Error here
```

**Update: 4/21/2016**

After painstaking analysis (errr... trial, error, repeat for ever) I have narrowed this down to the fields in the "Shared Columns" section of the "Document Set Settings" It seems when I check any of those the error occurs.  When I uncheck all the fields so none are shared I am able to add the folder.

**Update: 4/26/2016**

Here are the exact steps needed to recreate this error.
[image]

Here is the exact console program used to create the folder:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string pwd = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SOME_PWD", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pwd))
        {
            System.Console.Write("MSOPWD user environment variable empty, cannot continue. Press any key to end.");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }

        // Get access to source site
        using (var ctx = new ClientContext("https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/demo3"))
        {

            //Provide count and pwd for connecting to the source
            var passWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in pwd.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
            ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("me@email.com", passWord);

            Web web = ctx.Web;


            string docSetLibName = "P1";
            string docSetFolderName = "Test1";
            string folderName = "Foo1";

            try
            {
                List list = EnsureTargetTestFolder(ctx, docSetLibName);
                Folder docSet = EnsureTestDocumentSet(ctx, list, docSetFolderName);
                MakeStandardFolder(ctx, docSet, folderName);

            }catch(Exception exp)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR:" + Environment.NewLine);
                Console.WriteLine(exp.Message + Environment.NewLine);
                Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
                Console.ResetColor();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done...");

        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static List EnsureTargetTestFolder(ClientContext ctx, string docSetLibName)
    {
        if (ctx.Web.ListExists(docSetLibName) == false) {

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("List {0} not found... creating new!", docSetLibName));

            // Make the list
            List newList = ctx.Web.CreateList(ListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary, docSetLibName, false, true, "", true);

            newList.AddContentTypeToListByName("DocSetTest");
            newList.RemoveContentTypeByName("Document");
            newList.EnableFolderCreation = true;

            return newList;

        }else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("List {0} exists!", docSetLibName));
            return ctx.Web.GetListByTitle(docSetLibName);
        }
    }

    private static Folder EnsureTestDocumentSet(ClientContext ctx, List list, string docSetLibName)
    {
        if (list.RootFolder.FolderExists(docSetLibName) == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Document Set '{0}'does not exist... creating new!", docSetLibName));
            Folder fldr = list.RootFolder.CreateDocumentSet(docSetLibName, ctx.Web.GetContentTypeByName("DocSetTest").Id);
            return fldr;

        }else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Document Set '{0}\\{1}' exists", list.EntityTypeName, docSetLibName));
            return list.RootFolder.ResolveSubFolder(docSetLibName);
        }
    }

    private static void MakeStandardFolder(ClientContext ctx, Folder docSet, string folderName)
    {
        if (docSet.FolderExists(folderName) == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Folder {0} does not exist ... creating new!", folderName));
            docSet.CreateFolder(folderName);
        }else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Folder {0} already exists", folderName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tested set shared column in document set , with below code the folder created successfully: Web web = ctx.Web;ctx.Load(web);ctx.ExecuteQuery();Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List prjLib = web.Lists.GetByTitle("DLib");ctx.Load(prjLib);var projLibRootFldrs = prjLib.RootFolder;ctx.Load(projLibRootFldrs, pf => pf.Folders);ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry(); Folder f = projLibRootFldrs.EnsureFolder("Test");f.CreateFolder("d"); "DLib" is my document library name , "Test" is my custom document set name

Comment: @NanYu Does your custom document set contain additional column fields other than the default.  Furthermore, does your custom document set us the "Shared Columns" using those additional columns?  My tests  conclude when "Shared Columns" are checked no folder can be created.  When they are unchecked I am able to create a folder.

Comment: Yes , my custom document set contain additional column fields and have set all the columns(include default column) as "shared".

Comment: My test clearly show it not working.  I will update my post with the exact details of my test.

Comment: @NanYu please compare your steps to those I just updated in my post.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick to making this work was to first access and remove the  fields in the SharedFields collection of the DocumentSetTemplate, then make the folder, then restore the SharedFields.  Here are the methods used to do this.

```
    private static void HideSharedFields(ClientContext ctx, ContentType ct, out SharedFieldCollection unsharedFields)
    {
        DocumentSetTemplate docSetTemplate = DocumentSetTemplate.GetDocumentSetTemplate(ctx, ct);
        SharedFieldCollection sharedFields = docSetTemplate.SharedFields;
        unsharedFields = sharedFields;

        ctx.Load(sharedFields);
        ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();

        foreach(var fld in sharedFields)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format(" - Removing SharedField '{0}'", fld.Title));
            docSetTemplate.SharedFields.Remove(fld);
            fld.UpdateAndPushChanges(true);
        }

        docSetTemplate.Update(true);
        ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();
    }

    private static void RevealSharedFields(ClientContext ctx, ContentType ct, SharedFieldCollection unsharedFields)
    {
        DocumentSetTemplate docSetTemplate = DocumentSetTemplate.GetDocumentSetTemplate(ctx, ct);

        foreach (var fld in unsharedFields)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format(" + Adding SharedField '{0}'", fld.Title));
            docSetTemplate.SharedFields.Add(fld);
            fld.UpdateAndPushChanges(true);
        }

        docSetTemplate.Update(true);
        ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the steps you provided . Yes , with your steps the error occured .
I notice the "DocSetTest ID" column may cause the error :

1.create "DocumentSetName ID" column and make it shared , the error occured .

2.create "ID" column and make it shared , the error occured .

3.create "DocumentSetName_ID" column and make it shared , it works fine .

4.create "IDDocumentSetName" column and make it shared , it works fine .

So maybe your "ID" or "DocumentSetName ID" column may conflict something (perhaps existed "ID" column) when using  OfficeDevPnP.Core library. Try to change the name of the columns and check the results .

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  Maybe this method is relying on the DisplayName ('DocSetTest ID' & 'DocSetTest Leader') instead of the Static or Name property ('DocSetTest_x0020_ID' & 'DocSetTest_x0020_Leader') of the field.  I'll try to rename the field before attempting to create the folder to see what happens.

Comment: Looks like a dead-end.  I was able to rename the DisplayName, StaticName but not the Name attribute of the SchemaXML.  Updating the Name attribute does not persist when saved back to SharePoint it will appears to always revert to the name defined in the Content Type.  So attempting to add the folder still fails.  If you find a way to update those fields dynamically so that the folder can be created let me know.  Thanks